# Customize named font sizes depending on the screen-size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a xamarin.forms app, how could I customize named font sizes depending on the screen-size for the default ones don't work for me?

```
mainScale.LabelFontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)) * 2.5;
```

I've hardcoded 2.5 because it looks better.

Could you please let me know how I could have these hardcoded ones changed to a dynamic factor in a cross-platform app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across a cross-platform screen resolution solution given by Allan Ritchie [GitHub link](https://github.com/aritchie/deviceinfo) and the nuget package is [Nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.DeviceInfo/)

In the shared .net standard library, in the respective ContentView, the below code works:

```
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        // specific font adjustment code goes here
        if (CrossDevice.Hardware.ScreenHeight > 600)
        {
        ...              
        }
        ...

        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a Idea to how to create sizes.

App.xaml.cs

```
public static double DisplayScreenWidth = 0f;
public static double DisplayScreenHeight = 0f;

public static double Size1 { get; private set; }
public static double Size2 { get; private set; }
public static double Size3 { get; private set; }

if(DisplayScreenHeight > 560)
{
     Size1 = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)) * 1.6;
}
else
{
     Size1 = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)) * 1.2;
}
```

Activity.cs

```
App.DisplayScreenWidth = (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
App.DisplayScreenHeight = (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels / (double)Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;
```

App.xaml

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile" >

<Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger  TargetType="Label"
                       Property="FontAttributes" 
                       Value="None">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Regular" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger  TargetType="Label"
                       Property="FontAttributes" 
                       Value="Bold">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSans-Bold.ttf#Regular-Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <!-- TAMANHO DE FONTES -->
        <Style x:Key="Size1" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:App.Size1}}"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Size2" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:App.Size2}}"/> 
        </Style>
```

Home.xaml

```
<label Text="Hello from Xamarin Forms" Style="{StaticResource Size1}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I get the Resources.DisplayMetrics not found error. Could you please let me know how I could get the DisplayMetrics in place?

Comment: [Check this link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/kZ4oS2smSg66pOVT1xj75w.png). This image may help you.

Comment: I've added the answer that solves the cross-platform issue. Thanks a lot for the help, Alan.