# Font not changing when view size changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

I am setting up a home screen that leads to other sections with interactions within them, I got everything working, but at lower screen sizes the test for the title above the button switches to two lines, then begins to overlap the button.

I've written up a bit to try and get the font to change sizes when the screen changes, but it doesnt seem to be doing anything. The labels Im editing are public labels, so they should change right?
[Broken Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUXei.png)

```
void OnContentViewSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ContentView view = (ContentView)sender;
    // Portrait mode
    if (view.Width > view.Height)
    {
        view.WidthRequest = view.Height;
        view.HeightRequest = view.Height;
    }
    else
    {
        view.HeightRequest = view.Width;
        view.WidthRequest = view.Width;
    }
    //Do FontCalc for button Text
    FontCalc buttonTextLowerFontCalc = new FontCalc(buttonTextLabel, 10, view.Width);
    FontCalc buttonTextupperFontCalc = new FontCalc(buttonTextLabel, 100, view.Width);

    while (buttonTextupperFontCalc.FontSize - buttonTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize > 1)
    {
        double fontSize = (buttonTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize + buttonTextupperFontCalc.FontSize) / 2;

        FontCalc newFontCalc = new FontCalc(buttonTextLabel, fontSize, view.Width);

        if(newFontCalc.TextHeight > view.Height)
        {
            buttonTextupperFontCalc = newFontCalc;
        }
        else
        {
            buttonTextLowerFontCalc = newFontCalc;
        }
    }

    buttonTextLabel.FontSize = buttonTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize;
    buttonTextLabel.Text = buttonTextLabel.Text.Replace("??", buttonTextLabel.FontSize.ToString("F0"));

    //Do FontCalc for title Text
    FontCalc titleTextLowerFontCalc = new FontCalc(titleTextLabel, 10, view.Width);
    FontCalc titleTextupperFontCalc = new FontCalc(titleTextLabel, 100, view.Width);

    while (titleTextupperFontCalc.FontSize - titleTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize > 1)
    {
        double fontSize = (titleTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize + titleTextupperFontCalc.FontSize) / 2;

        FontCalc newFontCalc = new FontCalc(titleTextLabel, fontSize, view.Width);

        if (newFontCalc.TextHeight > view.Height)
        {
            titleTextupperFontCalc = newFontCalc;
        }
        else
        {
            titleTextLowerFontCalc = newFontCalc;
        }
    }

    titleTextLabel.FontSize = titleTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize;
    titleTextLabel.Text = titleTextLabel.Text.Replace("??", titleTextLabel.FontSize.ToString("F0"));
}

struct FontCalc
{
    public FontCalc(Label label, double fontSize, double containerWidth)
    {
        FontSize = fontSize;

        label.FontSize = fontSize;
        SizeRequest sizeRequest = label.Measure(containerWidth, Double.PositiveInfinity);

        TextHeight = sizeRequest.Request.Height;
    }
    public double FontSize { private set; get; }
    public double TextHeight { private set; get; }
}
```

Font size should change when the screen size changes, but doesnt. No Errors

Comment: I did not understand the code part in `while (buttonTextupperFontCalc.FontSize - buttonTextLowerFontCalc.FontSize > 1)`? Can you explain more? I would recommend you to have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401255/customize-named-font-sizes-depending-on-the-screen-size) for some idea.

Comment: What's the actual issue? Is the code called at all? Are the sizes calculated correctly? Please add some more details to your question.